# block specific url in .htaccess and allow access by IP

Tags: .htaccess

I have a problem, I want to secure the admin panel of my website using .htaccess but its a CGI script.

from WebBrowser it looks like: http://mysite.com/?op=adminpanel

of course its /cgi-bin/index.cgi?op=adminpanel

**I've tried with:**

```
<files index.cgi?op=adminpanel>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from my.ip.address
</files>
```

but not working, works when I use `<files index.cgi></files>` but the whole site got 403 error for everyone except for my ip

**now i'm testing with:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !( my.IP)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?op=adminpanel)
RewriteRule index.cgi - [F]
```

any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Per [this article](http://www.netshinesoftware.com/blog/restricting-access-to-a-url-by-ip-address-using-mod-rewrite/) you can do it like this:

Let's say you want to block IP address 123.255.123.255 from accessing the page www.mydomain.com/index.php?option=com_my_special_component. Here is how you could write the rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.255\.123\.255
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_my_special_component [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
```

The first line just turns on URL rewriting. The second line matches the IP address (use backslashes before each dot), the third line matches the querystring (ie. anything that comes after the ? in the URL) - in this case it would match if option=com_my_special_component comes anywhere in the URL after the ? (eg. index.php?id=1&option=com_my_special_component&action=dostuff would still match with this rule). The [NC] at the end of that line tells it to apply the rule regardless of whether any of the characters in the URL are uppercase or lowercase. The final line redirects the user to index.php with a 'forbidden' header - so they will get an error message in their browser, and tells mod_rewrite to stop interpreting any further rewrite rules.

If you want to ban multiple IP addresses, you can add new lines for them, but you need to add an [OR] flag to the end of each line except the last one - for example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.255\.123\.255 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^124\.255\.124\.255 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^125\.255\.125\.255
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_my_special_component [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
```

Since you are block access to an admin page, you probably want to only allow your IP. In that case you would just put an exclamation mark in front of the IP address to say if it's any IP other than this one, then rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.255\.123\.255
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^124\.255\.124\.255
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^125\.255\.125\.255
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} option=com_my_special_component [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=10.0.0.1
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=10.0.0.2
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=10.0.0.3
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
if the url begins with /admin and the remote address is not one of the three listed, send the browser on its merry way.
```

reference : https://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/chat/restrict-urls-starting-with-abc-to-specific-ips-.htaccess-guru

you can change this line (`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin`) to this :

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/admin`

for very url contain "/admin".